# Import csv with 1 json column

Tags: r, csv

I've been trying to import a .csv file (comma seperated), however there is one column in JSON format. This gives problems while trying to import the data as a dataframe in one go. I've been trying read.table and read.csv, but I cannot find the right solution (or similar questions on stack).

Is there an easy way to load the dataframe, and depict the 1 JSON column as string column? e.g. "[{"..." : "..." , "...": "..."}]"   Basically everything between the "[{ }]" should end up in 1 column in the final dataframe. 
It's extra challenging (for me) since the ',' is present in the JSON column, and should not be regarded as split there, but should for splitting the rest of the columns.

Desired output:
df =

```
    V1 V2 V3 JSONCOLUMN
    x  y  z  "[{"..." : "..." , "...": "..."}]"
```

Comment: Can you post some minimal sample data from your csv file?

Comment: firstRow = c("Date",  "Time Number",  "Fun","JSON_COLUMN")
secondRow = c("2-2-1900", "14:09:56", 4, TRUE, "[{"message":"nothing","description": 'hello", "otherField": "ciao"}])")

something like this is what the csv file looks like, however I cannot replicate it exactly in R, since this way of writing it down does not work entirely, due to the " characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a somewhat hacky way:

```
# Read csv
df <- read.csv(text =
    '"Date", "Time", "Number", "Fun", "JSON_COLUMN"
    "2-2-1900", "14:09:56", 4, TRUE, "[{"message":"nothing","description": "hello", "otherField": "ciao"}])"');

# Add double quotes for keys and values
df$JSON_COLUMN <- gsub("(\\w+):(\\s*)(\\w+)", "\"\\1\":\\2\"\\3\"", df$JSON_COLUMN)
df;
#Date      Time Number   Fun
#1     2-2-1900  14:09:56      4  TRUE
#                                                   JSON_COLUMN
#1  [{"message":"nothing","description": "hello", "otherField": "ciao"}])
```

Explanation: Since `read.csv` strips double quotes from the JSON string, we add them back in using a regular expression.